Energy and momentum conservation for light reflection
There is a radiation pressure which means that when light reflects from a surface, the surface will get some momentum/energy.
If so, what is the balancing change on the light/radiation side if light speed is constant?
Does it mean that the frequency of the wave will decrease to balance this change and keep energy/momentum in the system constant?
